# Rebasing and merging in clear case

Tags: clearcase

While rebasing the development stream in clear case, there are some times where a file needs to be merged because the local version is out of sync with one in the recommended baseline.
 Now intuitively, I was thinking that merge  tool will offer two options :file 1(local) and file 2:(in recommended baseline).
But in reality, I am being asked to choose from 3 files. What are these 3 files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 files are:

- common ancestor (or "base contributor")
- source (or "source contributor")
- destination

This is a three-way merge. See "[What are the basic clearcase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)"

(and the fourth screen is the end result)

See also "[How files and directories are merged](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm)"

[image: merge]