# clearcase merge issue because of old updated code checkin

Tags: merge, clearcase

I am having a major issue with clearcase merge:

I have a list of files taken from clearcase long time back and updated outside clearcase. In between, the same files have changed in clearcase as well. Now, I created a new branch and checked in the updated code from outside in the new branch.

But when I want to merge from new branch to integration branch, it automatically merges and overwrites the changes in integration branch with the changes from new branch. What I would have expected it to atleast raise a conflict and not wipe out the changes made in clearcase integration branch.

can anyone help here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful from *which version* you are starting your new branch.

If you are starting a new branch from the LATESt version of the current branch, in order to:

- clearfsimport your code modified outside of ClearCase
- merge said new branch to your current branch

Then, yes, all changes will overwrite the current versions.

But if you make your branch from an *older* version (a previous label or UCM baseline), import your code *there* and merge, *then* the merge will work or generate conflict if appropriate.

In other words, you need to start your branch from what you estimate is a **common ancestor** for your merge to work.
See "[Rebasing and merging in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691168/6309)":

[image: ClearCase merge].

Comment: thanks. But thats the problem I dont know when this code was taken from clearcase and updated so i dont know the common ancestor. But is this a common thing with clearcase? I am still not able to understand how it works and overwrites the code instead of raising an issue?

Comment: @user2636464 you must find a version of your current code which you believe could be a common ancestor. If you merge `C2` while `C2` is done on top of `C1` (meaning `B` equals `C1`, that is: `C1` -- the destination -- is also the base, or common ancestor), then a merge from `C2` to `C1` will simply overwrite `C1`.

Comment: @user2636464 by the way, I see you asked ClearCase questions before. Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer?